# xquery group names by alphabetical order to create contact list

Tags: xml, group-by, xquery

I have an xml with entry elements. Each entry has an author. I am trying to group the entries in such a manner such that each group consists of entries whose author name starts with a unique alphabetic character. All entries whose author names start with letter 'a' should be in one group, all entries whose authors whose names start with letter 'b' should be in another group, and so on..

```
let $feeds := 
  <feed>
     <entry>
       <author>a</author>
       <title>Title a</title>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <author>b</author>
       <title>Title ba</title>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <author>ab</author>
       <title>Title ab</title>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <author>bb</author>
       <title>Title bb</title>
     </entry>
   </feed>
for $entry in $feeds/entry
  let $author := $entry/author
  order by $author ascending
    return
      $entry
```

Returned Result:

```
<entry>
  <author>a</author>
  <title>Title a</title>
</entry>, <entry>
  <author>ab</author>
  <title>Title ab</title>
</entry>, <entry>
  <author>b</author>
  <title>Title ba</title>
</entry>, <entry>
  <author>bb</author>
  <title>Title bb</title>
</entry>
```

I am trying to tweak around the code such that the returned result looks something like so:

```
<group>
<author-group>
<entry>
  <author>a</author>
  <title>Title a</title>
</entry>, <entry>
  <author>ab</author>
  <title>Title ab</title>
</entry>
</author-group>
<author-group>
<entry>
  <author>b</author>
  <title>Title ba</title>
</entry>, <entry>
  <author>bb</author>
  <title>Title bb</title>
</entry>
</author-group>
<group>
```

In my example, two author groups are expected - First author group consisting of all authors whose names start with a, second author group consisting of all authors whose names start with b

I would like to ignore cases in author names i.e. aa and Aa are treated as same.

I would then take each author group and create a contact list.

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XQuery transformation**:

```
 <groups> 
 {
 let $entries := /*/entry,

  $vals := $entries/author/lower-case(substring(.,1,1))
      return
         for $fst in  $vals[index-of($vals, .)[1]]
           order by $fst 
             return
              <author-group>
                  {$entries[$fst eq lower-case(substring(author,1,1))]}
              </author-group>
   }
 </groups>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <author>a</author>
    <title>Title a</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <author>b</author>
    <title>Title ba</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <author>ab</author>
    <title>Title ab</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <author>bb</author>
    <title>Title bb</title>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<groups>
   <author-group>
      <entry>
         <author>a</author>
         <title>Title a</title>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <author>ab</author>
         <title>Title ab</title>
      </entry>
   </author-group>
   <author-group>
      <entry>
         <author>b</author>
         <title>Title ba</title>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <author>bb</author>
         <title>Title bb</title>
      </entry>
   </author-group>
</groups>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an XQuery 1.0 solution:

```
let $feeds :=  
  <feed> 
     <entry> 
       <author>a</author> 
       <title>Title a</title> 
     </entry> 
     <entry> 
       <author>b</author> 
       <title>Title ba</title> 
     </entry> 
     <entry> 
       <author>Ab</author> 
       <title>Title ab</title> 
     </entry> 
     <entry> 
       <author>Bb</author> 
       <title>Title bb</title> 
     </entry> 
   </feed>
return
<group>{
  for $initial in distinct-values($feeds/entry/author/lower-case(substring(.,1,1)))
        order by $initial
  return
    <author-group>{
      for $entry in $feeds/entry[author/lower-case(substring(.,1,1)) eq $initial]
      let $author := $entry/author 
      order by $author ascending
      return
        $entry
    }</author-group>
}</group>
```

HTH